# Placing a Menu beside a image in html and css

Tags: html, css

I have an image that i have displaying at top of the webpage.Now i want to show one menu button id beside to the image but i am not able to do it.Menu button is coming down in next line..

Here is the HTML..

```
  <img src="images/hotelAwadh.png" alt="logo" width="150" height="50">
  <div id="result_data"></div>
```

How to display `<div id="result_data"></div>` beside to `img` .

Please help me ..

Comment: You should read a CSS tutorial somewhere. This is really too basic to ask for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
float:left;
```

On both your image and div

Comment: @emisfera Why image came down ?

Comment: @emisfera <div id="result_data"></div> is coming a little down to img.Why?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I can't really say what is causing this. Maybe other parts of your HTML or CSS. it would be helpful if you could provide some more code

Comment: @emisfera i have updated my code with css.Please check

Answer (score 0):

`div` is a block element and it takes 100% width by default. `img` is an inline element by default and it occupies its very specific width/height. what you have to do is overwrite their default behaviours with `display:inline`and `display:block`

```
img {float:left;display:block}
div#result_data {float:left;display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v2N7v/